# Convert flat array [k1,v1,k2,v2] to object {k1:v1,k2:v2} in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

Is there a simple way in javascript to take a flat array and convert into an object with the even-indexed members of the array as properties and odd-indexed members as corresponding values (analgous to ruby's `Hash[*array]`)?

For example, if I have this:

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ]
```

Then I want this:

```
{ 'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f' }
```

The best I've come up with so far seems more verbose than it has to be:

```
var arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ];
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += 2) {
    obj[arr[i]] = arr[i + 1];
}
// obj => { 'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f' }
```

Is there a better, less verbose, or more elegant way to do this? (Or I have just been programming in ruby too much lately?)

I'm looking for an answer in vanilla javascript, but would also be interested if there is a better way to do this if using `undercore.js` or `jQuery`. Performance is not really a concern.

Comment: You can create your own function, then it's quite short: `var obj = transform(arr);`  ;)

Comment: That seems rather concise to me.

Comment: You have it right.  The loop you provided is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Yeah what you have is optimal.

Comment: other than your loop breaking if your arr has an odd number of elements, what you did looks fine; just wrap it in a function as already suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty sure this will work and is shorter:

```
var arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ];
var obj = {};
while (arr.length) {
    obj[arr.shift()] = arr.shift();
}
```

See [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

Comment: No guarantees about speed, however.

Comment: I like this! But you should probably note as a caveat that this consumes the original array, so it only works if you don't care about the original.

Comment: Character wise it is shorter but is it truly the most optimal solution? A question for the ages...

Comment: @ChaosPandion, it depends on how you define optimal. The "optimizatoin" I was looking for a concise and readable version, and this fits the bill for me.

Comment: You could also do this: `var obj = {}, k, v; while(k = arr.shift(), v = arr.shift()) { obj[k] = v;}`, which would even work with an odd number of elements (ignoring the last one).

Answer (score 5):

```
var arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ];
var obj = arr.reduce( function( ret, value, i, values ) {

    if( i % 2 === 0 ) ret[ value ] = values[ i + 1 ];
    return ret;

}, { } );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it multiple times you can also add a method to the Array.prototype:

```
Array.prototype.to_object = function () {
  var obj = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i += 2) {
    obj[this[i]] = this[i + 1]; 
  }
  return obj
};

var a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ];

a.to_object();    // => { 'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first chunk your array into groups of two:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

so that your data is now in a valid format to be used by [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), which will build your object for you:

```js
const chunk = (arr, size) => arr.length ? [arr.slice(0, size), ...chunk(arr.slice(size), size)] : [];
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
const res = Object.fromEntries(chunk(arr, 2));
console.log(res); // {a: "b", c: "d", e: "f"}
```

With underscore.js and lodash, you don't need to implement the `chunk()` method yourself, and can instead use `_.chunk()`, a method built into both libraries. The full lodash equivalent of the above would be:

```js
// lodash
> _.fromPairs(_.chunk(arr, 2)); 
> {a: "b", c: "d", e: "f"}
```

Using [`_.fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#fromPairs) provides better browser support, so if using lodash, it is preferred over `Object.fromEntries()`

Similarly, we can use [`_.object()`](https://underscorejs.org/#object) if you're using underscore.js to build the object:

```js
// underscore.js
> _.object(_.chunk(arr, 2));
> {a: "b", c: "d", e: "f"}
```