# Convert List to Structure Using Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've apologize if this is a trivial task, and I've also been googling and searching high and low for some solution I can get my head around but so far no dice. So anyways....

I have this:

```
var myList = "key1,value1,key2,value2"
```

And I want to populate a struct with this string so I can reference it like this:

```
alert(myList.key1)  // displays value1
```

Thoughts?  There's probably some way to do this with JQuery's `.each()` perhaps?  I'm seriously lost either way! Maybe just because it's really late and I've been stumbling through familiarizing myself with JS and JQuery again after a long hiatus.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8751034/218196). You just have to create the array, which is easily done via `.split()`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you never have commas in the values, you could start by using `split`:

```
var parts = myList.split(",");// ["key1", "value1", ...]
```

From there you can just use a simple loop:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i+=2) obj[parts[i]] = parts[i + 1];
```

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751218/990877) answer points out, you can also write the loop like this:

```
var obj = {};
while (parts.length) obj[parts.shift()] = parts.shift();
```

This is a neat way to write this, but behaves differently: after this loop, `parts` will be empty.

Comment: Also have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8751218/990877), which offers a very elegant elegant solution using [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

Answer (score 2):

[String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method is your first choice when it comes to string parsing tasks

```
var myList = "key1,value1,key2,value2"
var result = {}

myList.replace(/(\w+),(\w+)/g, function($0, $1, $2) {
    result[$1] = $2
})
```