# adding array to google dynamic retargeting tag

Tags: jquery, google-ads-api

I am new to this site and to developing with jQuery so I am sorry if this is a newbie question. I have been tasked with adding an array of products that are on the page to a google dynamic retargeting tag. I have my array filled with the correct data but I cant seem to add it to the tag as a variable. I am getting a parsing error saying "Expected ':'" within visual studio 2013 here is the code:

```
 var productsString = JSON.stringify(products, null, 4);

    var google_tag_params = {  

        productsString    /* ERROR HERE */
    };
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 1030976867;
    var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    var google_remarketing_only = true;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're missing your parameter name.

Comment: They are inside of my array productsString. So do you think I will have to iterate thru the array and spit them out in a loop?

Comment: Elements in associative array have to be declared as `keyname: 'value'`. See http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements in associative array have to be declared as `keyname: 'value'`.

So your code needs to look like this:

```
var google_tag_params = {  

    keyname: 'value'
};
```

In your case, since `productsString` contains an array of your elements, you will need to convert it to an associative array. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751034/convert-flat-array-k1-v1-k2-v2-to-object-k1v1-k2v2-in-javascript) for information on how to do that.

http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html

Comment: Yeah I cannot do a loop inside of the google_tag_params I'm struggling with seeing how this will work.